# Continuity of Projection operator from Tangent Bundle to Manifold

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I've been struggling with this problem for several hours now and I would appreciate some assistance. This is the only part of the larger problem that I am stuck on.

The Tangent Bundle $TM$ of a differentiable manifold $M$ is defined by the following:

$TM := \sqcup_{x \in M} T_xM = \{(x,y)|x \in M \text{ and } y \in T_xM\}$.

$TM$ inherits a manifold structure from $M$ and has dimension $2m$.

I wish to prove the following claim:

Claim: Given a differentiable manifold $M$ of dimension $m$, the projection operator $\pi: TM \mapsto M$ defined by $\pi(x,v) = x$ is continuous.

How do I proceed with the proof? Clearly the projection operator is continuous, correct? My first instinct is to take an open set $\chi \subseteq M$ in the sense that the coordinate charts/patches for $M$ form a countable basis for the (Hausdorff) topology on $M$. Then I would show that $\pi^{-1}(\chi) \subseteq TM$ is open. However, I am not finding properties of $\pi$ in a suitable way to show continuity.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The projection is not only continuous, it is smooth.

Recall the charts for $TM.$ Given a chart $(U,\varphi)=(U,x^i)$ for $M$  we have a chart $(\pi^{-1}(U),\tilde{\varphi})$ for $TM,$ where $\tilde{\varphi}:\pi^{-1}(U)\to \varphi(U)\times \mathbb{R}^n$ is given by $\tilde{\varphi}(p,v^i\partial/\partial x_i|_p)=(\varphi(p),v^1,\ldots,v^n).$

Then $\pi$ in the coordinates $(U,\varphi)$ for $M,$  $(\pi^{-1}(U),\tilde{\varphi})$ for $TM$ is given by
$$ \varphi\circ\pi\circ \tilde{\varphi}^{-1}(q,v^1,\ldots,v^n)=\varphi\circ\pi(\varphi^{-1}(q),v^i\partial/\partial x^i|_p)=\varphi(\varphi^{-1}(q))=q,$$
so it is smooth. Therefore $\pi$ is smooth as a map $TM\to M.$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In fact, the goal of the overall problem is to prove that $\pi$ is smooth. The problem I am having lies here: a function $F: M \mapsto N$ between smooth manifolds is smooth near $p \in M$ if for all charts $\langle U, \phi \rangle$ containing $p$ and all charts $\langle V, \psi \rangle$ containing $F(p)$, $\psi \circ F \circ \phi^{-1} : \phi(U \cap F^{-1}(V)) \mapsto R^n$ is smooth, which requires that the set $\phi(U \cap F^{-1}(V))$ be an open set. Taking $U \in TM$ and $V in M$, how do I prove that $\phi(U \cap \pi^{-1}(V)$ is open? It helps if $\pi$ is continuous

Comment: Given two topological spaces $X,Y$ and a map $F:X\to Y,$ $F$ is continuous iff for any $x\in X$ and any $V\subset Y$ open containing $F(x)$ there exists $U\subset X$ open containing $x$ such that $F(U)\subset V.$ Given $(p,v)\in TM$ and $V\subset M$ open containing $\pi(p,v)=p,$ let $U$ be a chart containing $p$ and contained in $V.$ Then $\pi^{-1}(U)$ is open in $TM,$ contains $(p,v)$ and $\pi(\pi^{-1}(U))\subset U\subset V.$ Thus $\pi:TM\to M$ is continuous.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome!